# Dragon Age: Inquisition - which area is for my level?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I'm little bit confused with "level vs area" progression in Dragon Age: Inquisition. Could someone give quick reference which zone is meant for which (character) level to be played?

Hinterlands seems like starting area, but after some time, all zones seems like little bit overpowered for my hero while hinterland map, except few higher level (like level 12 rifts) areas, starts to feel both an easy and without new quests.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just came across [this Reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/dragonage/comments/2nad8y/community_effort_minimum_level_for_zones/), which lists the following indications (from what I've experienced, they seem correct):

- Haven: 1+ (1-4)
- Hinterlands: 2+ (4-7, 8-12)
- Val Royeaux: 4+ (4-6)
- Storm Coast: 5+ (7-11, 13-15)
- Fallow Mire: 8+ (8-10, 12-15)
- Forbidden Oasis: 8+ (8-12, 5-15, 18-20)
- Skyhold: 10+
- Crestwood: 10+ (10-13)
- Western Approach: 10+ (10-14)
- Exalted Plains: 10+ (10-16)
- Emerald Graves: 12+ (14-20)
- Emprise du Lion: 16+ (16-22)
- Hissing Wastes: 16+ (19-23)

Be sure to head into Exalted Plains around 10-12 - it's a fun zone. I didn't go there until last night, at level 17, which makes everything a bit too easy.

Personally, I stayed in Hinterlands until about 8, at which point the only remaining stuff to do was like level 12-ish. I then went to Storm Coast, Forbidden Oasis and Fallen Mire, where leveling was slow enough to make me around 10-12 before moving on the main quest and finishing off Hinterlands. After that, I started Crestwood and The Western Approach - following the areas in the main quests.

Another note: don't be afraid to move the main quest, I thought I might finish it early but it's paced very well and it unlocks more stuff to do. By the time I got to an important point (after which the game really opens up) I was already 25 hours in and had barely done anything noteworthy.

Comment: How did you figure this order out ? That game gives no clues without going there and dying instantly before realising its too soon to travel there.

Comment: Some zones are hinted at or found through the main quests. The level ranges are an approximate based on enemy and quest levels.

Comment: For new people seeing this, going to a zone early isn't always the best idea even if you can beat the area. The game scales enemies to an extent so going a few levels higher isn't going to hurt. The reason is that some zones lock their chests to your level for the rest of the game. Going to the western approach at 10-14 will lock you out of tier 3 chests for the remainder of the game. So you would want to wait until tier 3 chests are available at level16 before coming here.

Answer (score 6):

After you completed the basics in the Hinterlands, I'd strongly recommend to continue the main quest in Val Royeaux. That part is pretty short and opens up new options for you, especially in companion choice.

The next part of the main quest can be done at a low level as well.

The Storm Coast is the next area that has low-level enemies around level 5-7. The Forbidden Oasis is a bit higher level, but not that much. The Fallow Mire is the one area that is unlocked early that you should probably avoid at first, I returned quickly after only encountering level 12 enemies.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problems. Halfway through the Hinterlands, Fallow mire opened up so I tried going there.... Not a nice experience.
MISSING a helper text on the areas like they made for the main quest line. A warning would be nice before you step into a group of undead that are 5-6 levels above you...

Finished hinterlands at about 8
Went to Stormcoast and stayed till 10
Fallow mire done at 11
now I have no idea where to go next.
Main quest says hept the empress 12-15 and im still 11 so im kind of stuck too.

Comment: Exactly the same here... Little tip for this: Locking a target allows you to see his level (I wasn't using that feature at all before that).

Answer (score 0):

While some areas are made for certain levels, they are also designed for you to leave and come back later when your party is at a higher level. You're suppose to start on the hinterlands, work it a bit leave and do some other sections.

Hinterlands, The Storm Coast, Forbidden Oasis, Val Royeaux, Mage/Templar quest area.
All those areas can be done between 4-12.

The Fallow Mire is around lvl 12ish area.

If you find an area to hard, go to the war room and look around for an area to unlock, this should help you keep pace level wise. This is also why there are camps everywhere so that you can fast travel in and out.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure most of the enemies level with you, but have a minimum level. For example Farrow Mire zombies are at least level 8, but if you visit it later when you are level 12, they will be level 11. But some, like Hinterlands dragonlings, stay the same level no matter what.

So pop in, see if area is reasonable for your character, if not - pop out. There's no harm in that.

Comment: The problem with that method is chest locking. You won't know until later in the game but there really is something you don't always want to do. Refer to my comment on the accepted answer.